# click, tap, touchstart in jquery which when? and how?

Tags: android, jquery, gestures

So.. I am developing the mobile versions of my website and noticed that my 'rating' script whereby a user selects a certain number of stars did not work on the iPad.

The functionality worked with a jquery .on('click' in a normal web browser.

I googled it and found tap and touchstart

Changing the function to .on('click touchstart' made it work on the iPad. Great !

I have now implemented a form where on checking a checkbox some extra fields are shown/hidden.
Again I used .on('click' - this time I was trying it on an android phone. The .on('click' didnt work for a checkbox..? I tried adding touchstart with no success. I then added tap and bingo it works.

Doing a little more research i noted others saying not to bind two gestures as in certain situations the event could be triggered twice. Fair enough.

COuld someone thus advise and explain how 'clicking' works with different elements on normal web browsers, android devices, and i devices.

An example of how you can then implement only using one gesture, but the right one depending on the device would be great.

N.B Im just using normal jquery.

Many Thanks

Comment: For checkbox, **change** event handler is more appropriate

Comment: Can you elaborate as to why?